# IntelliJ IDEA find matching parenthesis / bracket

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

Is there any keyboard shortcut to navigate from one parenthesis `(` to the matching one `)` in IntelliJ?

Or even to "jump to the next opening/closing parenthesis `(`/`)` from wherever my cursor is"?

And, if there's no way to do it 'natively', are there any plugins that could add this functionality quickly and easily?

EDIT: the best solution I've found is added as a comment in liango's answer below, namely to put the cursor on the first or last brace and then press `CTRL-W` twice. Not ideal, but it does the job!

Comment: There is no built in functionality for that, AFAIK. But you could try **AceJump** and **emacsIDEAs** plugins. What they offer is not "direct" jump .. but some advanced stuff .. which may not be suitable for you (too "advanced" -- with AceJump it's like "Ctrl+;" then ")" and then what ")" you want to jump to -- 3 keys in total).

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll give AceJump a whirl and see how it goes. If anybody else has any suggestions for alternatives please do share.

Comment: please also vote for [IDEA-12068](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12068)

Comment: One of the most useful questions here on this website.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use CTRL-W to expand the selection within a bracket, use repeatedly if needed to select further out, then use the arrows.

Comment: That's an interesting hack to get there - thanks for sharing. (I need to find a new mapping for it, though.. CTRL-W is 'close document' in my set up)

Comment: Best solution I've found: put the cursor on the first/last brace and then press CTRL-W twice.

Answer (score 65):

- You can use `Ctrl + [` and `Ctrl + ]` to navigate to a code block's start and end.
- You can also use `Ctrl + Shift + M` to navigate between the start and end of a code block.

On Mac, you can use `Option + Cmd +[` and `Option + Cmd + ]`, and `Ctrl + M`

---

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-braces.html

Comment: Thanks - this is now the correct answer (some 2 years after the question was first asked). Although, I think it's something like `Ctrl + [` to go to nearest `{` and `Ctrl + Shift + [` (which is `Ctrl + {`) to SELECT to the nearest `{`

Comment: @caponica Uh yeah.. I'm sorry I've mistaken something there. You're right, `Ctrl + paranthesis` does not work.

Comment: On Mac, you can use `Option + Cmd +[` and `Option + Cmd + ]`, and `Ctrl + M`.

Comment: This does not work for german keyboards. You have to reassign the key to Ctrl+8 and Ctrl+9, where the brackets sit, but require Alt Gr to be pressed.

Comment: This does answer the original question as to how to jump to matching paranthesis.

Answer (score 36):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> is the Windows/Linux default shortcut for action "Move caret to matched brace". (For other environments see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html?keymap=secondary_intellij_idea_classic#code_block_braces) and use the Shortcuts dropdown in the top right of the page.)

Or if desired, the shortcut keys can be changed as follows:
Go to Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions, or just type the name in the search box.

Comment: I'm trying to get matched parentheses `()` not braces `{}` :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. It works for all types of brackets, []{}()<>. [Ctrl+Shift+M](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/navigating-to-braces.html)

Comment: @SteveChambers IJ has ~5 keymap schemes across 3 OSs. In what environment are those the default shortcut?

Comment: @voddan Good point - I've modified your answer to specify the environment and provide a link for other environments.

Comment: For Mac it's `^+M` -- saved you some clicks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the latest and greatest as of version 2020.1

To move caret between matching code block braces, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

To navigate between code blocks, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

From [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#find_cursor_edit)

> ### Navigate with the caret﻿
>
> To navigate backwards, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>← Left</kbd>. To navigate forward, press
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→→ Right</kbd>.
>
> To navigate to the last edited location, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
>
> To find the current caret location in the editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This
>   action might be helpful if you do not want to scroll through a large
>   file.
>
> However, you can press the Up and Down arrow keys to achieve the same
>   result.
>
> To highlight a word at the caret you are trying to locate, select Edit
>   | Find | Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret from the main menu.
>
> To see on what element the caret is currently positioned, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
>
> To move caret between matching code block braces, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
>
> To navigate between code blocks, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.
>
> To move the caret forward to the next paragraph or backward to the previous one, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for the **Move Caret Forward a Paragraph** or **Move Caret Backward a Paragraph action**.
>
> You can also select a text and then move the caret forward or backward to a paragraph. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and search for the **Move Caret Forward a Paragraph with Selection** or **Move Caret Backward a Paragraph with Selection action**.

Comment: I also recommend `Move Cared to Code Block Start/End Code with Selection`  bound to shift + option + command + `[` and `]` on Mac by default. Also if you do not remember keyboard shortcuts you can use `shift` x2 to open the command palette, and Actions search section to look up actions by typing their name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: This is incorrect - as stated above, I'm trying to jump between (...) not {...}